# React-router v4, URL changing but component doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've tried everything but fail to render component when URL changes. No error messages nothing, react-redux is installed but not using it yet, so it can't be the problem. When I check it from to Google chrome React dev tools, nothing happens, there is no match, history vs anything. I couldn't find a solution, is there any way to make it work?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vm3x9n4k67

Here is my `NavBar.js`. I import `NavLink` from react-router-dom and implement these

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from "./NavBar.css";
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';


const NavBar = (props) => {
    return (
    <div className={classes.NavBar}>
        <h1 className={classes.NavBar_list} >foodbase</h1>
        <ul className={classes.NavBar_list}>

            <NavLink to="/auth"> <li className={classes.NavBar_list_item}>Signin</li></NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/"><li className={classes.NavBar_list_item}>Main Page</li></NavLink>

        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavBar
```

this is my Layout.js render property:

```
 render() {
          let recipes = [];
          if (this.state.recipes.length > 0) {
          recipes = this.state.recipes;
    }

    return (

        <div>
            <NavBar/>
            <SearchBox
                onChangeHandler={this.onChangeHandler}
                value={this.state.inputValue}
                onSearchClick={this.onClickedHandler} />
            <section className={classes.SearchSection}>
                <ul className={classes.SearchResultArea}>
                    <SearchResults
                        Results={recipes}
                    ></SearchResults>
                </ul>
            </section>

        </div>
    )
}
```

and finally app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Auth from './components/Auth/Auth';
import SearchBox from './components/SearchBox/SearchBox';
import Layout from './containers/Layout/Layout';
import './App.css';



class App extends Component {
  render() {

  return (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Layout>
          <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={SearchBox} />
        </Layout>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

[image: when clicked Signin]

[image: Main Page]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you need to put your `Route` components directly into `Switch` and don't forget to render `children` in `Layout`. So try this:

**app.js:**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {

  return (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={SearchBox} />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Layout.js**

```
render() {
  // ...

  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      { this.props.children } // <-- your route specific components
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It is still not working but as you said it might be something about props.children, but how

Comment: Besides the changes proposed by @streletss, you need to return in your `Auth.js` component:  `return form;` because right now you are returning an object instead the HTML you are building up.