# Unable to render react components upon clicking the Links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a react application in which I have wrapped layout components for the other routes, the thing is when I click the links present in the sidebar(part of layout) they are not being rendered on the screen, here is my code.

App.js

```
//Imports here
<Provider store={store}>
 <Router>
   <Switch>
     <Layout>
       <Route exact path="/admin" render={() => <Admin />} />
       <Route exact path="/employees" render={() => <Employees />} />
       <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
     </Layout>
   <Switch>
 </Router>
</Provider>
```

Layout.js

```
//imports here
//styling here
<Link to='/employees' />
// and likewise for rest of the routes
```

When clicking the links ie, employees or profile they aren't being rendered, tried console.log to see if my layout was obstructing that, but no use. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your URL is changing but the content is not being rendered, the problem is this, apart from wrapping the Routes as mentioned in @G.aziz 's answer since the routes are children WRT layout components we have to use {props.children} inside the layout component to render the content like so...

Layout.jsx

```
<div>
<Sidebar />
<Navbar />
{props.children} // here we are rendering the routes which we mentioned in the switch component in App.js
</div>
```

For me this solution fixed. Also please refer this question for further information.  [React-router v4, URL changing but component doesn't render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468247/react-router-v4-url-changing-but-component-doesnt-render?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

It should be inside the `Switch` component but you can wrap it with a  `Layout` component like that.

```
const Headers = () => (
  <Layout>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/admin">Admin</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/employees">Employees</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </Layout>
);


function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Layout>
            <Header></Header>
           <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/admin" render={() => <Admin />} />
            <Route exact path="/employees" render={() => <Employees/>}/>
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
           </Switch>
          </Layout>
        </Router>
      );
    }
```

Comment: What's Header component in this context?

Comment: fixed! actually, since the route components are children to the routes we need to use {props.children} to render  them actually!

Comment: @Yashwanthsomayajula add your answer and accept it if you see it as the right one